# Loading bar based on ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

I would like to include a loading bar in my website when I make an ajax call to load a new page. How can I set the width of the bar in proportion to the level of loading of ajax call?
For example:
Initially the width of the bar is set to zero. -> You click on a link in proportion to the ajax call the bar width increases -> got 100% back to 0% (or disappears).

it is possible something like that? Alternatively how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to the `.ajax()` call:

```
$.ajax({
    /* All your usual code */
    xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        myXhr.addEventListener( "progress" , updateProgress , false );
        return myXhr;
    }
});


function updateProgress( evt ) {
    console.log( 'updateProgress' );
    console.log( evt );
    /* :TODO: Your logic here */
    if ( evt.lengthComputable ) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        // ...
    } else {
        // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
    }
}
```

Comment: As a comment, I have used this for file upload progress, not for page upload progress, so I am not 100% confident in it.

Answer (score -2):

```
function ajaxLoadContent(x) {
    // non se utilizzare questo per via della compabilità di HTML5
    // e.preventDefault(); 
    $('#front').html('<div class="alert alert-warning">Caricamento della pagina...</div>');
    pageurl = $(x).attr('link');
    $.ajax({
        url: pageurl,
        cache: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $('div#front').html(data);
            stopRefreshShout();
        },
        xhr: function () {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            //Upload progress
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    //Do something with upload progress
                    console.log(percentComplete);
                }
            }, false);
            //Download progress
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    //Do something with download progress
                    console.log(percentComplete);
                    console.log(evt.loaded);
                    $('.progress.progress-striped.active.loader-page').css('width', evt.loaded + '%');
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        }
    })
    if (pageurl != window.location) {
        window.history.pushState({
            path: pageurl
        }, '', pageurl);
        $("body").addClass("historypushed");
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is my code. But the loading bar doesn't work. Where is the problem?

Comment: Don't make a new XMLHttpRequest.  Load it from current settings.

Comment: Fixed. But it does not work, the bar will charge up to 1%. Where is the problem?
Here there is the code -> [link](http://pastebin.com/JsiNDrCW)

Comment: You need to multiply percentages by 100. 100% technically does equal 1 (1.00).  50% is 0.5